# Iptables - Bridge and Forward chain

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, bridge

I have setup ethernet bridge `br0` that contains two interfaces `eth0` and `tap0`

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif eth0
brctl addif tap0
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 promisc up
ifconfig tap0 0.0.0.0 promisc up
ifconfig br0 10.0.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.0.1.255
```

My default `FORWARD` chain policy is `DROP`

```
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

When i do not add following rule the traffic is not passing through bridge.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p all -i br0 -j ACCEPT
```

As far as I understand `iptables` is only responsible for IP layer.

`ebtables` should be responsible for filtering traffic on the ethernet bridge.

**So why do I have to add ACCEPT rule in iptable's FORWARD chain?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because of the br-nf code that is available as a patch to linux 2.4 and used in linux 2.6:

> The br-nf code makes bridged IP
>   frames/packets go through the iptables
>   chains. Ebtables filters on the
>   Ethernet layer, while iptables only
>   filters IP packets.

Since the traffic you are working is ip, `iptables` rules still apply because of *br-nf* passing the bridged packets to `iptables`.

[This](http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html) is a great resource to read about the interaction and [this one](http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/documentation/bridge-nf.html) details the functionality of *br-nf* code, including how to disable all or some of the functionalities (i.e. not passing bridge traffic to iptables).

Comment: The functionality is not working on 4.4.0-22-generic (ubuntu 16.04), even after I did `echo "1" > /sys/devices/virtual/net/br0/bridge/nf_call_arptables`. Any ideas?

Comment: Answering myself:
# Load br_netfilter
modprobe br_netfilter
 # Add to BROUTING chain rule to forward all ipv4 packets to iptables
 ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -p ipv4 -i br0 -j DROP

Answer (score 13):

You can disable this behaviour (letting iptables handling bridged packets) by typing:

```
echo "0" > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables
```

(see http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/documentation/bridge-nf.html)

Comment: Also, /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-ip6tables

Answer (score 7):

If you do not have the need to use iptables with the bridge on your system you can permanently disable it by using either of the following:

1. Adding an iptables rule:

`iptables -I FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-is-bridged -j ACCEPT`

2. Or editing /etc/sysctl.conf:

`net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
 net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
 net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0`

Answer (score 0):

The ebtables chains won't see frames entering on a non-forwarding bridge port. Might take a look at this: http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html