# eth0 on lxc does not work

Tags: networking, bridge, lxc

I am facing some problems that the eth0 on lxc container does not work. I already tried
[Bridging LXC containers to host eth0 so they can have a public IP](https://serverfault.com/questions/445991/bridging-lxc-containers-to-host-eth0-so-they-can-have-a-public-ip), but it does not help.

On my host (Ubuntu on virtualbox):

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

config

```
# cat /var/lib/lxc/config
lxc.config
lxc.utsname=ubuntu
lxc.network.type=veth
lxc.network.link=br0
lxc.network.flags=up
```

I created a container with the above config

```
# lxc-create -t centos -f config -n centos1
```

then launch

```
# lxc-start -d -n centos1
# lxc-console -n centos1
```

It seems veth is properly connected because the host machine says

```
# brctl show
bridge name    bridge id           STP enabled    interfaces
br0            8000.080027bb0aca   no             eth0
                                                  veth48BKPz
lxcbr0         8000.000000000000   no
```

And the default gateway seems also be set correctly on the host

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination    Gateway        Genmask          Flags    Metric  Ref   Use  Iface
0.0.0.0        192.168.11.1   0.0.0.0          UG       100     0       0  br0
10.0.3.0       0.0.0.0        255.255.255.0    U        0       0       0  lxcbr0
192.168.11.0   0.0.0.0        255.255.255.0    U        0       0       0  br0
```

On the lxc container

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination    Gateway        Genmask          Flags    Metric  Ref   Use  Iface
0.0.0.0        192.168.11.1   0.0.0.0          UG       0       0       0  eth0
169.254.0.0    0.0.0.0        255.255.0.0      U        1009    0       0  eth0
192.168.11.0   0.0.0.0        255.255.255.0    U        0       0       0  eth0
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have iptables (or ip6tables) enabled on your host ?  If you do, [you need to ACCEPT the traffic on the FORWARD chain of your bridge](https://serverfault.com/questions/162366/iptables-bridge-and-forward-chain) with:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p all -i br0 -j ACCEPT
```

The reason is that the br-nf (bridge-net filter) option is [enabled by default](http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/) in the 2.6 kernel, so the bridged traffic goes through iptables.  You [could disable it](http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/documentation/bridge-nf.html) by doing:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-arptables
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-ip6tables
```

Follow this link for more information on [ebtables/iptables interaction on a Linux-based bridge](http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html).