# Iptables not working on a bridged setup

Tags: iptables, bridge

I am trying to block DNS requests using an Ubuntu machine. I have created a bridge and the packets are being forwarded as expected. 
Only when I add iptables rules, it is not taken in account. I tried with no rules, simply setting the policy of each table to DROP and even this doesn't work : the packets are still transmitted without interruption. 
I should precise that I'm working in an ISP context so, network-wise, the bridge is situated on the WAN side, between the CPE and a telindus. 
Thanks for the help.

Version of iptables : 1.4.21

`# iptables -L -n -v`

`0 packets in forward and input, 16 in output` (Rather synthetic as I'm on my phone)

All policies are in DROP mode.

`/proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables` = 1

The configuration of the bridge is rather simple :

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0
brctl addif br0 eth1

ifconfig eth0 up
ifconfig eth1 up
ifconfig br0 up
```

Comment: At least [edit] this question to show us the non-working rule. We have no hope of helping you fix your problems if you don't show us what isn't working for you.

Comment: I didn't explicitly said it but as of now there is no rule, I simply set all policies on DROP, which had no effect. So this is a rather simple configuration in the end

Comment: In what OSI layer iptables works? In what layer bridge works?

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant? Isn't iptables supposed to process bridges packets? My previous searches has shown me that the br-nf code makes it that way : http://serverfault.com/a/162384/364071

Comment: Maybe the bridge does not pipe the traffic through iptables?
What does > cat /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables say?

Comment: I checked it before and it was at 1

Comment: What are the exact interfaces between which you want to filter traffic?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen: eth0 and eth1, but the filtering has to be transparent.

Comment: Alright so, after some more research, I'll have to check those when I'm at my job: 
`bridge-nf-filter-vlan-tagged`
`bridge-nf-filter-pppoe-tagged`
As I am exactly in both those cases (802.1Q encapsulated into PPPoE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question : the problem was coming from the following parameters :

```
/proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-filter-pppoe-tagged
/proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-filter-vlan-tagged
```

I set them to 1 and it allowed the subsequent frames/packets to be forwarded into iptables FORWARD table. 
Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Would be useful to share with us iptables -L -n -v

In order to drop a traffic on bridged interface, just use:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 53 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp --dport 53 -j DROP
```

Feel free to use

```
tcpdump -i any -n port 53
```

to see wheras the traffic really goes through the server.

You can also use:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables: " --log-level 4
```

to log the traffic that passes through iptables.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm on a phone so I can't paste info. I already see the traffic using Wireshark and I know it's passing through.

Comment: At first I used the udp line you wrote, and as it didn't do a thing, I just set every policy to DROP to be sure. Hence the topic.

Comment: If you have DROP policy on FORWARD chain and traffic still passes through, then you have something strange in your network.

Comment: The strangest is that the packets passing through a wifi interface I have on the machine are showing into the tables, so it's probably not a problem related to iptables.